# Spring boot test always returns an immutable list

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, mockito

When I try to run unit tests with Mockito using the following syntaxis for creating Lists

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList())
Arrays.asList()
```

The code always seems to return immutable lists and I get a unsupportedoperationexceptions all the time as I cannot remove elements from this List.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, see also in the related JavaDoc of `Arrays.asList()`:

> The returned list implements the optional Collection methods, except those that would change the size of the returned list. Those methods leave the list unchanged and throw UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Is there any way with the MockMvc or the ObjectMapper to have mutable Lists when making Rest endpoint calls?

Comment: If you want to create an empty mutable list, you can just opt for ```new ArrayList<>();```